# System.Web has been removed in ASP.NET 5, so how do I find the new places?

Tags: asp.net-core

So I jsut managed to deploya very basic MVC site on Ubuntu, behind nginx served by kestrel. Fantastic.

Now I just wanted to do a simple thing like show the visitors reported IP address, just for fun. You know, I want it to lead up to SQL/MySql get the whole feature set going on within Ubuntu.

But System.Web was removed from `aspnet50` and broken down and you cannot just access `System.Web.HttpContext...` or `Reaquest.UserHostAddress()`

I can see `@Request` but I doesnt have all the properties I would be expecting.

How do I find... or am I supposed to find which dependency to add which contains that feature or any other feature I might be looking for from the full .NET 4.5 MVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quickly find out which package might contain a type you're looking for, check out the totally unofficial [Reverse Package Search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/). Just type in something like `IPAddress` and you'll get a list of packages that are good hints.

It's of course not 100% reliable, but it's better than guessing.

Comment: To whoever downvoted without a comment: If the answer does not seem satisfactory, please let me know why so that I can fix any issues. I do believe my answer directly addresses how to resolve the problem at hand.

Comment: Not sure why you got down voted? But that is what I was looking for. The search doesn't work to great but I can deal with it. Is that your site? Thanks +1

Comment: Not my site, but one of the people on the ASP.NET team (the team I work on) wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have JetBrains' [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it also provides context actions to find a namespace or a type on NuGet:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Finding_Exploring_and_Installing_NuGet_Packages.html